# RailsAdmin custom field for has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

Using [RailsAdmin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) with this example:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable, inverse_of: :commentable
  has_paper_trail
end
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true, inverse_of: :comments
  has_paper_trail
end
```

When I am viewing a Product, the  `has_many` associated Comments is a comma separated list of the Comment names.  I'd like instead to have a table with various attributes the the Comment model in columns.

Further, the default edit view on Product gives me a list of Comments  that might be related to other Products, and allows the user to "steal" the Comment and assign it to the current one in view.  I guess that might be useful in a Manager/Employee type of association - it would allow a user to switch a Employee from one Manager to another.  It's really not what I want though.  Instead, I'd like to present a list of existing Comments associated, ability to delete one of these, and ability to add one.

So I'm looking for a starting point on this type of customisation (assuming it's beyond the realm of configuration).  I have seem some tips on field customisation but this is something different (isn't it?)  I haven't been able to find anything on the web so I'm hoping someone here can get me started...

Thanks,

Comment: This sounds like you're after some advice on your views. Can you include your view code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RailsAdmin does not currently allow for custom partials for the Show action.